# Zimbra SOAP SearchRequest returns unknown document error

Tags: soap, zimbra

I am trying to send the `SearchRequest` to find the stuff I need in the mailbox. However, I keep on getting the `unknown Document` error.

```
POST /service/soap HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Accept: text/xml
Host: 192.168.138.133
Content-Length: 514
Expect: 100-continue

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <authToken>%token acquired from AuthRequest%</authToken>
    <context xmlns="urn:zimbra" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchRequest xlmns="urn:zimbraMail">
      <query>is:unread</query>
    </SearchRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It seems to me, that I have the wrong `xmlns` specified, but [the zimbra soap api reference](http://zimbra.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zimbra/trunk/ZimbraServer/docs/soap.txt?revision=843&view=markup) says that the namespace should be `zimbraMail`. Still I keep on getting the error.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a session somewhere in the headers ? (inside context)

http://dropcanvas.com/521xc/91

Comment: When I send `AuthRequest` it returns no session to me. Only an `authToken`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<soap:Header>
    <context xmlns="urn:zimbra" >
          <authToken>%token acquired from AuthRequest%</authToken>
    </context>
  </soap:Header>
```